# Virtual Machine Manager - Automate Repetitive Launch Steps

Tags: debian, virtual-machine, libvirt

Each time I launch Virtual Machine Manager, I have to run this command before any virtual machines can be run successfully:

```
sudo virsh net-start default
```

On a Debian 11 desktop, how can I configure Virtual Machine Manager so that this is accomplished by merely launching the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell libvirt that the "default" network should be automatically started when libvirtd is started.

```
sudo virsh net-autostart default
```

If "default" hasn't already been started, you'll still need to start it manually one last time but the next time you reboot, "default" will be auto-started along with libvirtd.

FYI, `virsh` has built-in help, e.g.:

```
# virsh help network
 Networking (help keyword 'network'):
    net-autostart                  autostart a network
    net-create                     create a network from an XML file
    net-define                     define an inactive persistent virtual network or modify an existing persistent one from an XML file
    net-destroy                    destroy (stop) a network
    net-dhcp-leases                print lease info for a given network
    net-dumpxml                    network information in XML
    net-edit                       edit XML configuration for a network
    net-event                      Network Events
    net-info                       network information
    net-list                       list networks
    net-name                       convert a network UUID to network name
    net-start                      start a (previously defined) inactive network
    net-undefine                   undefine a persistent network
    net-update                     update parts of an existing network's configuration
    net-uuid                       convert a network name to network UUID
    net-port-list                  list network ports
    net-port-create                create a network port from an XML file
    net-port-dumpxml               network port information in XML
    net-port-delete                delete the specified network port

# virsh help net-autostart
  NAME
    net-autostart - autostart a network

  SYNOPSIS
    net-autostart <network> [--disable]

  DESCRIPTION
    Configure a network to be automatically started at boot.

  OPTIONS
    [--network] <string>  network name or uuid
    --disable        disable autostarting
```

Comment: Do you see any harm in auto-starting this upon reboot? Ideally, I want it to only "Auto-Start" if I launch the Virtual Machine Manager application, but I'd like it to remain off otherwise. I don't know how to create a pre-launch step for this application. And, I worry that if I do figure it out, I'll still have to enter my password each time I launch, due to `virsh net-start default` requiring `sudo`. Your answer helps me avoid authentication, but it starts virsh earlier than I'd like.

Comment: Nope, can't see any harm.  If you need the network started for your VM(s) then it should be started when libvirtd is started. It's common to start libvirtd on boot, but it's not essential, you can always start/stop it manually if you want.   And if you want to do that without needing to enter a password for sudo, write a simple script that does just and configure sudo to allow you to run that script without a password.  You could write one script that takes either a stop or a start arg, or one script to start it and another to stop it.  This, BTW, is how sudo is supposed to be used.